# Every $k$-regular graph with girth 5 has at least $k^2+1$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Show that the number of edges in a $k$-regular graph with girth $5$ is at least $k^2+1$.

The $\textit{girth}$ of a graph is the minimal size of a cycle in $G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with an arbitrary vertex $v$ in $G$. Since $G$ is $k$-regular, $v$ has exactly $k$ neighbours, say $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k$. Now, each $v_i$ has $k-1$ neighbours other than $v$. Note that no two $v_i$'s can be adjacent in $G$, for if $v_iv_j$ were an edge in $G$ for some $i,j$ with $i\ne j$, the vertices $v,v_i,v_j$ would form a cycle of length $3$, contrary to the hypothesis that $G$ has girth $5$. Thus, each $v_i$ is adjacent to $k-1$ vertices $v_{i1},v_{i2},\cdots,v_{i(k-1)}$, all of which are different from each other for all $i$. Thus, the vertex set $V(G)$ of $G$ contains $v$, the $v_i$'s, and the $v_{ij}$'s (and possibly many more), which are $1+k+k(k-1)=k^2+1$ in number, implying that $|V(G)|\geqslant k^2+1$.

The proof is complete. $\square$